# Would an object launched by the Catapult spell do full damage against a Scarecrow?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, damage-resistance

A Wizard uses the spell [*Catapult*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/catapult) ([EEPC, p. 15-16](https://media.dnd.wizards.com/EE-Players-Companion_0_0.pdf#page=15); XGtE, p. 150) against a [Scarecrow](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/scarecrow) (MM, pg. 268).

Catapult flings an object that is not worn or carried toward a scarecrow and hits.

The scarecrow has damage resistance to *bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing from nonmagical attacks*.

**Does *Catapult* do full damage, or reduced damage in this scenario?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### The catapult does full damage

The catapult deals bludgeoning damage. Scarecrow, in its most recent version, has a resistance towards Bludgeoning, Piercing, and Slashing damage from Nonmagical *Attacks* (emphasis mine; see the monster's stat block on [DnDBeyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/scarecrow)). Catapult, however, is not an attack as the damage comes from a failed saving throw and not an attack roll, so the resistance does not apply.

You can find the change to the wording of the resistance in the Global section of the errata document [here](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/MM-Errata.pdf).

Comment: So if you used Bigby's hand to push them off a cliff they would take full damage from the fall? This seems to imply that any time you save vs. damage you would not get to apply your resistance.Is this a loophole that is only detrimental to monsters?

Comment: @Guy Only when the resistance says it's specifically against attacks. If it's a general damage type resistance without such stipulation, the resistance applies against any source of that type of damage.

Comment: Hmm. Well, I don't think I would personally rule this way in my game but the answer looks RAW backed so it shall be accepted!

Comment: @Guy Out of curiosity, would you personally rule otherwise for any spell dealing piercing/bludgeoning/slashing damage? Or elemental damage? What's your criteria for what's sourced from magic vs not?

Comment: @Guy [That's a separate damage situation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/148779/would-an-object-launched-by-the-catapult-spell-do-full-damage-against-a-scarecro#comment381530_148780) that deserves its own question, and I think already has one. I am pretty sure that the example question had to do with a werewolf falling off of a cliff. [Page 17, right hand column, Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=17)

Comment: @NautArch Since we're dealing with magic it is more about "feel" than any good real world example. If catapult magically created a rock and threw it, then I would see the damage as magically sourced. Otherwise it just seems like someone hit them very hard with a rock. In order to get to the root of this we'd probably have to dig down into what resistance actually is (instead of just what it does mechanically) and why magic would bypass that resistance.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast For sure. I'm not disputing the RAW answer to the question and I think kviiri did an excellent job of answering. I just fail to see the difference from someone hitting me with a rock vs. me falling very fast onto said rock (ground).

Comment: @Guy Not all game mechanics have equal verisimilitude.  The rock is a weapon attack (game mechanic thing) while falling damage is a different game mechanic.  That's where the Sage Advice ruling is coming from.  I am very much in favor of that ruling: other wise lowlevel characters may have no way to deal with a werewolf.  It allows them a way to deal with that immunity problem.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Let's assume Ogremoch (or another strong magical creature) picked up a bolder and threw it at the scarecrow/werewolf/whatever. Would you agree that that would be reduced damage? Also, did we get rid of chat? I seem to recall some rule about comments not being for chat.

Comment: @Guy, you are right, this is getting chatty, so if you are interested in further discussion we ought to take it to [RPG.SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=rpg.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I think I did this right? Maybe? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94271/catapult-spell-resistance